# Entity Framework Many to many relationship for Membership table. Code first approach

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement many to many relationship using Entityframework codefirst approach with webapi2 application.

**Issue:** Values not inserting in the third table.

**Additional info:**

If i am working with non membership table,its working fine. but when i do the mapping with ApplicationUser table ie table created by entity framework,the insertion is not happening. i am using bearer token authentication in this applicationuser table and also added some custom columns based on my requiremnets. i refered the below link

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a3d5d0/creating-many-to-many-mapping-using-code-first-entity-frame/.

**Questions:**

Can we do the many to many relation for Membershiptable(user,role) with other tables?

**Code i have tried :**

Model 1

```
public class Strata
{
    [Key]
    public Guid StrataID { get; set; }
    public string StrataNumber { get; set; }
    public string StrataName { get; set; }
    public string StrataType { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfUnits { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country required")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Zip code required")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string VerificationCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool? IsConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
      [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime SubscriptionStartDate { get; set; }
      [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime SubscriptionEndDate { get; set; }
    public int PaymentId { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public string SubscriptionType { get; set; }
    public bool PaymentStatus { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }


    public Strata()
    {
        ApplicationUsers = new List<ApplicationUser>();
    }

}
```

Model2

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
        public ApplicationUser()
        {
            Stratas = new List<Strata>();
        }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string ConfirmEmailAddress { get; set; }
        public bool   IsActive { get; set; }
        public string CurrentStatus { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfUser { get; set; }
        public bool ResetFlag { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Strata> Stratas
        {
            get;
            set;
        }  
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DbContextCondo", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); // This needs to go before the other rules!

            //modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("User");

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new StrataMap());
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");

        }
        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public DbSet<Strata> Strata { get; set; }


    }
```

Map1

```
 public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
    {

        public UserMap()
        {
            //Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

            this.Property(t => t.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");
            this.Property(t => t.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName");
            this.Property(t => t.ConfirmEmailAddress).HasColumnName("ConfirmEmailAddress");
            this.Property(t => t.IsActive).HasColumnName("IsActive");
            this.Property(t => t.CurrentStatus).HasColumnName("CurrentStatus");
            this.Property(t => t.TypeOfUser).HasColumnName("TypeOfUser");
            this.Property(t => t.ResetFlag).HasColumnName("ResetFlag");


            // Relationships
            this.HasMany(t => t.Stratas)
                .WithMany(t => t.ApplicationUsers)
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("UsersStratas");
                    m.MapLeftKey("Id");
                    m.MapRightKey("StrataID");
                });

        }

    }
```

Map2

```
public class StrataMap: EntityTypeConfiguration<Strata>
    {

        public StrataMap()
        {

            //Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.StrataID);

            this.Property(t => t.StrataID).HasColumnName("StrataID");
            this.Property(t => t.StrataNumber).HasColumnName("StrataNumber");
            this.Property(t => t.StrataType).HasColumnName("StrataType");
            this.Property(t => t.NumberOfUnits).HasColumnName("NumberOfUnits");
            this.Property(t => t.StreetAddress).HasColumnName("StreetAddress");
            this.Property(t => t.City).HasColumnName("City");
            this.Property(t => t.Province).HasColumnName("Province");
            this.Property(t => t.Country).HasColumnName("Country");
            this.Property(t => t.ZipCode).HasColumnName("ZipCode");
            this.Property(t => t.VerificationCode).HasColumnName("VerificationCode");
            this.Property(t => t.IsActive).HasColumnName("IsActive");
            this.Property(t => t.IsConfirmed).HasColumnName("IsConfirmed");
            this.Property(t => t.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");
            this.Property(t => t.SubscriptionStartDate).HasColumnName("SubscriptionStartDate");
            this.Property(t => t.SubscriptionEndDate).HasColumnName("SubscriptionEndDate");
            this.Property(t => t.PaymentId).HasColumnName("PaymentId");
            this.Property(t => t.Amount).HasColumnName("Amount");
            this.Property(t => t.SubscriptionType).HasColumnName("SubscriptionType");
            this.Property(t => t.PaymentStatus).HasColumnName("PaymentStatus");

        }
    }
```

controller

```
 public IHttpActionResult PostStrata(Strata strata)
        {
            DTOStrata strataInfo = new DTOStrata();
            try
            {

                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }
                strata.StrataID = Guid.NewGuid();
                strata.SubscriptionStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().ToString());

                if (strata.SubscriptionType == "Invoice Monthly")
                {
                    strata.SubscriptionEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6).ToShortDateString().ToString());

                }
                else
                {
                    strata.SubscriptionEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12).ToShortDateString().ToString());
                }

                strata.IsActive = true;
                strata.PaymentId = 1;
                strata.IsConfirmed = false;

                var verificationCode = VerificationCodeGenerator.GenerateOTP(6);
                strata.VerificationCode = verificationCode;
                db.Strata.Add(strata);
                db.SaveChanges();



            }
```

Please let me know if i have missed out anything in the code. or suggest me the better way of implementing the same.

Thanks
Dev

Answer (score 0):

What is your `OnModelCreating` method like? 
the mapping code Should be introduce in this method in the `dbContext`, check out this :

[Configure Many-to-Many relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

but if you want to use `EntityTypeConfiguration` for mapping, have you added your configuration to the model? for this you have to this code in your `OnModelCreating` method in `dbContext`:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap());

  }
```

To have a sample,look this: 
[Using the Code First Model ConfigurationClasses](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165720/Using-the-Code-First-Model-Configuration-Classes)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.                                                                                   1.yes like you said i tried mapping code in dbcontext, later tried with creating new mapping class. but in both case the same result... it didnt work. 2.I have already added the usermap in onmodelcreating method..please see my model2.